# Date format is not changed after executing alter system

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

The database is Oracle 11g2 Express. I executed `alter system set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD/MM/RRRR" SCOPE=SPFILE;` , and then I made a query : `select hire_date from employees;` but the format displayed is still DD/MM/RR ! So how to change `nls_date_format` permanently ?

Comment: What tool are you using to display your data?

Comment: What do you think `SCOPE=SPFILE` [means](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF53147)? Do you really want to change it at system level, which is usually ignored, rather than at session/client level?

Answer (score 1):

SCOPE = SPFILE, makes the change only in the static parameter file but not your current instance. When you restart the DB, the instance is built with the new value from SPFILE.

SCOPE = MEMORY, makes the change in the current instance but not in the static parameter file. When you restart the DB, the instance is built using the old value. So you lose the change.

SCOPE = BOTH, makes the change both in the current instance and in the static parameter file.

Whenever you restart the database, the instance is built using the values from static parameter file. In your case, when you restarted, the instance was built using the changed value. So it is working after you restarted the database. If you had used the value BOTH for SCOPE, then you need not have restarted the database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the they had used the value `SCOPE=BOTH` they'd have got ORA-02096; you can't modify this parameter in a running instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set NLS parameters at different levels

As initialization parameters on the instance/server.

```
SQL>alter system set V$NLS_PARAMETER = 'XXX' scope = both;
```

As environment variables on the client.

```
% setenv NLS_SORT FRENCH
```

As ALTER SESSION parameters.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET V$NLS_PARAMETER = = 'XXX'
```

Any setting overrides the setting on a higher level. So setting it server side does not guarantee that the setting is used by all clients connecting.

If you want to make sure it is set for every client connecting use a logon trigger. Even then a user can explicitly override the 'default' setting

LOGON TRIGGER to set those Parameters in Session level.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sys.schema_nls_session_settings AFTER LOGON ON BOB.SCHEMA
BEGIN
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''';
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_TERRITORY=''UNITED KINGDOM''';
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_CURRENCY=''£''';
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_ISO_CURRENCY=''UNITED KINGDOM''';
END;
/
```

Comment: Tools like SQL Developer also have a date format in their preferences. It's only used to display results in SQL worksheets. But it ignores any system and session settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I restarted the database and the format is then set !